# Service mysql shutdown

Tags: mysql, shutdown

The mysql service was stopped and in mysql log I saw these warning:

```
161125 16:41:10 [Warning] IP address 'x.x.x.x' has been resolved to the host name 'x.x.x.x.xxx.xxxxxx.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
161125 23:58:23 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

**Notice:**

- with iptable, only the server address is accepted for port 3306
- In my.cnf I set the bind_address = server_adress_ip: bind_address = x.x.x.x

Why the mysql service was stopped?

Comment: The warning at 16:41:10 can be ignored for the purposes of answering this question. What happened at 23:58:23? Have a look at the root bash history, and look in other logs to see whether there was anything else going on. Look at lastlog to see who was logged on.

Comment: is it now any other messages before 23:58:23? good to check syslog as well for same time (before and after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `WARNING` and a `NOTICE`, not an `ERROR`. Neither of them are responsible for the shutdown. I assume however you're getting this message because in your `/etc/hostname` (or dns) you have a polluted entry.

As for why mysql cares what the name resolves to, [here is a post on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codership-team/kXLmxCviDX0/QQk9jCkjA4AJ).

> This warning seems to come from MySQL ACL code. The reason is that 
>   reverse DNS lookup returns hostname which resembles IPv4 address 
>   (hostname starts with '98.158.'). One way to get rid of this warning 
>   and DNS lookups is to put
>
> skip-name-resolve
>
> in my.cnf. However, in this case you can use only IP addresses in 
>   MySQL grant tables. For more information see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dns.html.

If this is by intent, you may want to [read this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81132)

Comment: Great, thais is the best solution: using skip-name-resolve